# Why this Python 2 lambda with print doesn't work?

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.x

Can someone explain to my why this very simple lambda expression does not work and what exactly is wrong?

```
 In [8]: print_me = lambda x: print x
  File "<ipython-input-8-269dab9ac1a1>", line 1
    print_me = lambda x: print x
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but

```
print_me = lambda x: x
```

does ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python **2.X** `print` is a *statement* not a function. Accordingly, this is not supported by `lambda` functions. In python 3, however, `lambda x: print(x)` works since `print` is a function. You could also try to import the new `print` functionality in python 2.X:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
f = lambda x: print(x)
f(4)
```

which prints `4`.